# How to parse this string in Java?

Tags: java, string

> prefix/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/..

How to parse the `dir1, dir2` values out of the above string in Java?

The prefix here can be:

/usr/local/apache2/resumes

Comment: Can you make clear what are you trying to parse here?

Comment: Sorry,missed them out,just updated.

Comment: Are you trying to parse a URL?

Comment: That prefix totally changes the question.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

If you want to split the `String` at the `/` character, the [`String.split`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) method will work:

For example:

```
String s = "prefix/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4";
String[] tokens = s.split("/");

for (String t : tokens)
  System.out.println(t);
```

Output

```
prefix
dir1
dir2
dir3
dir4
```

**Edit**

Case with a `/` in the prefix, and we know what the prefix is:

```
String s = "slash/prefix/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4";

String prefix = "slash/prefix/";
String noPrefixStr = s.substring(s.indexOf(prefix) + prefix.length());

String[] tokens = noPrefixStr.split("/");

for (String t : tokens)
  System.out.println(t);
```

The substring without the prefix `"slash/prefix/"` is made by the [`substring`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int)) method. That `String` is then run through `split`.

Output:

```
dir1
dir2
dir3
dir4
```

**Edit again**

If this `String` is actually dealing with file paths, using the [`File`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html) class is probably more preferable than using string manipulations. Classes like `File` which already take into account all the intricacies of dealing with file paths is going to be more robust.

Comment: What if there is / character in prefix?

Comment: Shore, you should edit your question and clarify the possible values of prefix, dir1, etc, etc ... Are you tring to parse a URL?

Answer (score 3):

```
...
String str = "bla!/bla/bla/"

String parts[] = str.split("/");

//To get fist "bla!"
String dir1 = parts[0];
```

Answer (score 2):

In this case, why not use `new File("prefix/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4")` and go from there?

Answer (score 2):

```
String str = "/usr/local/apache/resumes/dir1/dir2";
String prefix = "/usr/local/apache/resumes/";

if( str.startsWith(prefix) ) {
  str = str.substring(0, prefix.length);
  String parts[] = str.split("/");
  // dir1=parts[0];
  // dir2=parts[1];
} else {
  // It doesn't start with your prefix
}
```

Comment: Almost - you are just parsing the prefix with that substr.  Try str = str.substring(prefix.length) instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
 String result;
 String str = "/usr/local/apache2/resumes/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4";
 String regex ="(dir)+[\\d]";
 Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile( regex ).matcher( str);
  while (matcher.find( ))
  {
  result = matcher.group();     
  System.out.println(result);                 
}
```

output-- 
dir1
dir2
dir3
dir4

Answer (score 1):

Using `String.split` method will surely work as told in other answers here.

Also, `StringTokenizer` class can be used to to parse the String using `/` as the delimiter.

```
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String []args)
    {
        String s = "prefix/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/..";
        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(s, "/");
        String dir1 = tokenizer.nextToken();
        String dir2 = tokenizer.nextToken();
        System.out.println("Dir 1  : "+dir1);
        System.out.println("Dir 2 : " + dir2);
    }
}
```

Gives the output as :

```
Dir 1  : prefix
Dir 2 : dir1
```

Here you can find more about [StringTokenizer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html).

Comment: Do you know other outdated classes to solve this task?

Comment: @Tom Is `StringTokenizer` a outdated class?

Comment: Have you checked the JavaDoc of StringTokenizer lately?

Comment: yes, found this : `StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the split method of String or the java.util.regex package instead.` thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
    String s = "pre/fix/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/..";
    String prefix = "pre/fix";
    String[] tokens = s.substring(prefix.length()).split("/");
    for (int i=0; i<tokens.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(tokens[i]);
    }
    }

}
```

Comment: There can have / in prefix too.
prefix here is not literally 'prefix'

Comment: Do you know the prefix going into the parse?  Then get the length of the prefix and use substring to before calling parse to just get the last segment of the string.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a File, you can get the parts by creating an instanceof File and then ask for its segments.

This is good because it'll work regardless of the direction of the slashes; it's platform independent (except for the "drive letters" in windows...)

Answer (score 0):

String.split(String regex) is convenient but if you don't need the regular expression handling then go with the substring(..) example, java.util.StringTokenizer or use Apache commons lang [1](http://commons.apache.org/lang/).  The performance difference when not using regular expressions can be a gain of 1 to 2 orders of magnitude in speed.

Answer (score -1):

```
String s = "prefix/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4"

String parts[] = s.split("/");

System.out.println(s[0]); // "prefix"
System.out.println(s[1]); // "dir1"
...
```

Comment: There can have / in prefix too.