# Parse time of format hh:mm:ss

Tags: java, date, string-parsing

How can I parse a time of format `hh:mm:ss` , inputted as a string to obtain only the integer values (ignoring the colons) in java?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question- if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Comment: So far, I have the user input the time as a string and that's it. I have done a fairly large amount of research but because I'm so new to programming it is hard to make sense out of what people say

Comment: [`java.text.SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: Something similar to get you started here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/950409/how-to-parse-this-string-in-java

Comment: You might take a look at the SO [FAQ] and [Ask] to get a better sense of what types of questions are appropriate here.

Comment: Try to write your question the way you feel. People will comment (maybe edit) your question in order to help you. Remember, it's better to ask a *silly* question that stay all quiet (because some silly questions can be answered with "you're wrong").

Comment: Found this with google, and it has exactly the question I was asking and exactly the answer I was looking for.  If that isn't Stack Overflow, I don't know what is.

Comment: This question was just what I was looking for.  Maybe not perfectly phrased but so what, it solved my problem!

Answer (score 89, accepted):

As per Basil Bourque's comment, this is the updated answer for this question, taking into account the new API of Java 8:

```
    String myDateString = "13:24:40";
    LocalTime localTime = LocalTime.parse(myDateString, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss"));
    int hour = localTime.get(ChronoField.CLOCK_HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int minute = localTime.get(ChronoField.MINUTE_OF_HOUR);
    int second = localTime.get(ChronoField.SECOND_OF_MINUTE);

    //prints "hour: 13, minute: 24, second: 40":
    System.out.println(String.format("hour: %d, minute: %d, second: %d", hour, minute, second));
```

Remarks:

- since the OP's question contains a concrete example of a time instant containing only hours, minutes and seconds (no day, month, etc.), the answer above only uses [LocalTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html). If wanting to parse a string that also contains days, month, etc. then [LocalDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) would be required. Its usage is pretty much analogous to that of LocalTime.
- since the time instant int OP's question doesn't contain any information about timezone, the answer uses the LocalXXX version of the date/time classes (LocalTime, LocalDateTime). If the time string that needs to be parsed also contains timezone information, then [ZonedDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) needs to be used.

====== Below is the old (original) answer for this question, using pre-Java8 API: =====

I'm sorry if I'm gonna upset anyone with this, but I'm actually gonna answer the question. The Java API's are pretty huge, I think it's normal that someone might miss one now and then.

A SimpleDateFormat might do the trick here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

It should be something like:

```
String myDateString = "13:24:40";
//SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
//the above commented line was changed to the one below, as per Grodriguez's pertinent comment:
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
Date date = sdf.parse(myDateString);

Calendar calendar = GregorianCalendar.getInstance(); // creates a new calendar instance
calendar.setTime(date);   // assigns calendar to given date 
int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR);
int minute; /... similar methods for minutes and seconds
```

The gotchas you should be aware of:

- the pattern you pass to SimpleDateFormat might be different then the one in my example depending on what values you have (are the hours in 12 hours format or in 24 hours format, etc). Look at the documentation in the link for details on this
- Once you create a Date object out of your String (via SimpleDateFormat), don't be tempted to use Date.getHour(), Date.getMinute() etc. They might appear to work at times, but overall they can give bad results, and as such are now deprecated. Use the calendar instead as in the example above.

Comment: Thank you VERY much for understanding and your answer.

Comment: Java 1.4 is quite old. Update the documentation links.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza right you are, updated the link.

Comment: 'hh' expects the hour to be in am/pm (1-12). Since you're using 13:24:40 in your own example, perhaps you should use 'HH' in the date format instead

Comment: With java 8 you can,   `LocalTime lt = LocalTime.parse("14:23:57");`

Comment: This Answer is now outdated, using troublesome old date-time classes now supplanted by the *java.time* classes.

Comment: @BasilBourque You are right. I've updated the answer to (also) explain how to do this using Java 8's new API

Comment: With Java 8 (java.time) you don’t need an explicit formatter (as @AsankaSiriwardena already said). Unless you need to validate that there is no fraction of second.

Answer (score 13):

A bit verbose, but it's the [*standard*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) way of parsing and formatting dates in Java:

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
try {
  Date dt = formatter.parse("08:19:12");
  Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
  cal.setTime(dt);
  int hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR);
  int minute = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
  int second = cal.get(Calendar.SECOND);
} catch (ParseException e) {
  // This can happen if you are trying to parse an invalid date, e.g., 25:19:12.
  // Here, you should log the error and decide what to do next
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Except that silently swallowing exceptions is rarely a great option. Makes it hard to find out what went wrong, when something goes wrong.

Comment: @yshavit: It was merely an example.

Comment: I understand, but given that the OP is a self-proclaimed beginner, I wanted them to understand that that part of the example is not something they should take literally.

Comment: to make yshavit happy: JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);

Comment: Update: it *was* the standard way of parsing and formatting a time in Java until 2014.

Answer (score 5):

```
String time = "12:32:22";
String[] values = time.split(":");
```

This will take your time and split it where it sees a colon and put the value in an array, so you should have 3 values after this.

Then loop through string array and convert each one. (with `Integer.parseInt`)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to extract the hours, minutes and seconds, try this:

```
String inputDate = "12:00:00";
String[] split = inputDate.split(":");
int hours = Integer.valueOf(split[0]);
int minutes = Integer.valueOf(split[1]);
int seconds = Integer.valueOf(split[2]);
```