# How to group items of Arraylist of time in HashMap in Kotlin?

Tags: android, hashmap, kotlin

I need to group the times together like 02:10 PM, 02:30 PM should come in group 02:00 PM - 03:00 PM. I am getting the all times in yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS+00:00 format. How to group the time together in 02:10 PM format?

Currently I converted them in hh:mm aa format and got the list, How to group them in Arraylists and finally store them in Map, So that I can list the times in Recyclerview?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like this (given `items` with the time values stored in `timeString`):

```
val format = SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa")
val calendar = GregorianCalendar.getInstance()

val groups = items.groupBy { item ->
    val date = format.parse(item.timeString)
    calendar.setTime(date)
    calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)
}
```

[<sup>(runnable demo)</sup>](https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/UserProjects/gimof9c5vdke30qcnfqcg5idcp/7imhtho55okr5c4rlgaet7era3)

See:

- [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)
- [`Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)
- [`groupBy { ... }`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/group-by.html)
- [java - Parse time of format hh:mm:ss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11994790/parse-time-of-format-hhmmss)

Comment: How to get 03:00 PM also in the current 02:00 - 03:00 PM group? Any idea @hotkey?

Comment: @SirajSumra, see [another demo](https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/UserProjects/c3e46gmrb4nokp3nbdghrua2l4/f0rut7oncb0ppkalcrfbnh1jdp), there I used the formatted strings as group keys. You might want to adjust the logic that sets the hour, though.

Comment: Your solution really worked. But there is an issue in selection of the items. Can you please look into this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46217375/android-issue-in-selection-and-deselection-of-items-in-an-adapter-kotlin