# Android issue in selection and deselection of items in an Adapter kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am creating a view to display time in grouping manner. For that I grouped items in an hashmap and passed it to the activity. From my activity, I am initializing the parent adapter to display the list in Linear fashion. In that parent adapter there is another child adapter with times items which are displayed using gridLayout manager in grid fashion.

The Image of the current scenario and the issue is as below:
[image]

Now the actual issue, I want to select only 1 time at a time. But as you see, different arraylist has different selections here. When I select 1 item from the same group, it works fine. But it is not deselecting other groups time. How can I achieve that?

Parent Adapter:

```
class TimePickerAdapter(context: Context, arrTimeSlots: ArrayList<ListItem>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

val mContext = context
val mList = arrTimeSlots

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup?, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    return if (viewType == ListItem.TYPE_HEADER) {
        TimeHeaderHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent?.context).
                inflate(R.layout.item_time_group, parent, false))
    } else {
        TimeSlotsHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent?.context).
                inflate(R.layout.item_time_child, parent, false))
    }
}

override fun getItemCount() = mList.size

override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
    return mList[position].type
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder?, position: Int) {
    if (holder is TimeHeaderHolder) {
        holder.itemView?.apply {
            with(mList[position] as TimeHeaderItem) {
                tvTimeGroupHeader.text = date
            }
        }
    } else {
        holder?.itemView?.apply {
            with(mList[position] as TimeSlotItem) {
                val mAdapter = TimeSlotsAdapter(mContext, pojoOfTimeSlots)
                rvTimeSlotsChild.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(mContext, 3)
                rvTimeSlotsChild.adapter = mAdapter
            }
        }
    }
}

inner class TimeHeaderHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)

inner class TimeSlotsHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)
```

}

My child Timeslots adapter -> In this adapter, I have written a code to select deselect time. But it is happening for the same group only.

```
class TimeSlotsAdapter(context: Context, arrTimeSlots: List<TimeSlots>?) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

val mContext = context
val mList = arrTimeSlots!!

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup?, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    return TimePickerHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent?.context).
            inflate(R.layout.item_time_picker, parent, false))
}

override fun getItemCount() = mList.size

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder?, position: Int) {
    holder?.itemView?.apply {
        with(mList[position]) {
            tvTimeView.text = convertedTime
            if (isSelected) {
                tvTimeView.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context,
                        R.drawable.time_rounded_corner_selected)
                tvTimeView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.white))
            } else {
                tvTimeView.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context,
                        R.drawable.time_rounded_corner)
                tvTimeView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.grey_text_7))
            }
        }
    }
}

inner class TimePickerHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    init {
        itemView.setOnClickListener {
            for (i in mList.indices) {
                mList[i].isSelected = false
            }
            mList[adapterPosition].isSelected = true
            notifyDataSetChanged()

        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Bad solution to use two adapters. Try to use one adapter with grid layout manager. You can set different type of grid items as in linear adapters. Also in this case you'll decide your problem.

Comment: @EduardKornev Can you provide any demo or something that how I can display linear items in Grid manager?

Comment: Try to explain you in answer

Answer (score 0):

Try to use one adapter with grid manager

```
GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getAppContext(), 3); 
gridLayoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() { 
        @Override
        public int getSpanSize(int position) {
        //define span size for this position
        //for example, if you have 2 column per row, you can implement something like that:
        if(position == youRule) {
            return 3; // 3 item in row
        } else {
            return 1; // 1 item in row
        }
    }
});
```

Also you should merge your two adapters in one. Unlike hashmap for your items, use sorted list item [header, time, time, time, header, time, time, time, etc]. Now you can simple check what item need to mark as selected.