# String conversion into time (only hh:mm)

Tags: java, android, time, simpledateformat, time-format

I want my String "10:10" to be converted into time in a format of hh:mm instead of MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss aa

```
Date date;
SimpleDateFormat sdf;
sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
try 
{
    date = sdf.parse(a.getString("time").toString());
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: "+date);
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: "+a.getString("time"));
}
 catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But i am getting this in my logcat

```
D/MTAG: onCreate: Thu Jan 01 10:00:00 GMT+05:00 1970
D/MTAG: onCreate: 10:00
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse time of format hh:mm:ss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11994790/parse-time-of-format-hhmmss)

Comment: I think you are wrongly understand Date and DateFormat. If you print out date object without any date formatter, it will display full date string.

Comment: The `LocalTime` class of JSR-310 (the modern Java date and time API AKA `java.time`) is made for you! You may use JSR-310 on Android through ThreeTenABP, see [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

Comment: An addition, `SimpleDateFormat` is long outdated and notoriously troublesome, and the modern date and time API is so much nicer to work with. I should say it’s a safe bet.

Comment: A `Date` cannot have a format in it, it always prints as `Thu Jan 01 10:00:00 GMT+05:00 1970` (its `toString` method produces this format). Any format  is always outside the `Date` and in a `String`. See [All about java.util.Date](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2017/04/23/all-about-java-util-date/).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Date changing format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44306533/java-date-changing-format)

Answer (score 2):

```
    String timeString = "10:10";
    LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse(timeString);
    System.out.println(time);
```

This prints

```
10:10
```

I am cheating a bit, though. The way I read your question, you asked for a date-time object with the format `HH:mm` in it. Neither a `LocalTime` object (used in the above snippet) nor a `Date` (used in your code) can have a format in it. What you get when you concatenate the `Date` to a string or print the `LocalTime` is the result of the object’s `toString` method, and you cannot change this method (only in subclasses, and you don’t want that). In other words, when you want a specific format, you need to have that format in a string outside the date-time object.

The lucky part is that `LocalTime.toString()` produces the format you want (as long as the seconds and fraction of second are zero; otherwise they would be in the string too).

Will that work on your Android device? It will. `LocalTime` is a class of JSR-310 also known as `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API introduced nearly 4 years ago, early in 2014. JSR-310 has been backported to Java 6 and 7 in ThreeTen Backport, which in turn has been adapted to Android in ThreeTenABP. So get ThreeTenABP, add it to your project and start enjoying how much nicer it is to work with than the outdated date and time classes.

PS There’s a bug in your format pattern string in the question: Lowercase `hh` is for hour within AM or PM from 1 through 12, which works nicely when the hours are 10, but not always. I am convinced that you want uppercase `HH` for hour of day in the interval 0 through 23. When I run your code with a string of `12:12`, I get Thu Jan 01 00:12:00 CET 1970. The hours are 0, not 12.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/), explaining how to use `java.time`.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/)
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where the modern date and time API was first described.

Answer (score 1):

> Date and time formats are specified by date and time pattern strings.
>   Within date and time pattern strings, unquoted letters from 'A' to 'Z'
>   and from 'a' to 'z' are interpreted as pattern letters representing
>   the components of a date or time string. Text can be quoted using
>   single quotes (') to avoid interpretation. "''" represents a single
>   quote. All other characters are not interpreted; they're simply copied
>   into the output string during formatting or matched against the input
>   string during parsing.

[Read Document](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

**Try this**:

```
  DateFormat aFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
  Date dt = aFormatter.parse("10:10");
  Calendar aCalander = Calendar.getInstance();
  aCalander.setTime(dt);
  int hour = aCalander.get(Calendar.HOUR);
  int minute = aCalander.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
```

Comment: @Omar Saleem  Accept any one of these answer!

Comment: FYI, this Answer uses troublesome old date-time classes now supplanted by the *java.time* classes. For earlier Android, see the *ThreeTen-Backport* & *ThreeTenABP* projects.  Much better: `LocalTime.parse( "10:10" )`

Comment: Yeah I accepting your point. But here in this question he using the same.

Answer (score 1):

When a Date is created, it will be in the format of "Thu Jan 01 10:00:00 GMT+05:00 1970" as you mention in your output. So if you want to display and play around with the format of the date you should use the format method in SimpleDateFormat. I hope the below code help you understand better.

```
//formatting date in Java using SimpleDateFormat
String date_s = "10:10"; 
SimpleDateFormat dt = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm"); 
Date date = dt.parse(date_s); 

System.out.println(date);   
System.out.println(dt.format(date));
```

Comment: FYI, this Answer uses troublesome old date-time classes now supplanted by the *java.time* classes. For earlier Android, see the *ThreeTen-Backport* & *ThreeTenABP* projects.  Much better: `LocalTime.parse( "10:10" )`