# How to isolate a component of a String?

Tags: java, string

I have a method that returns a `String`. That string called `contact` is made of multiple smaller strings. Those smaller strings were parameters to that method.

exemple :

```
String contact = id + " " + name + " " + telNum;
return contact;
```

Now I have another method that takes `contact` as a parameter but that needs to return ONLY name.

So my question is how can I isolate that smaller string `name` from the whole string contact?

Comment: This has obviously been answered multiple times already: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/950409/how-to-parse-this-string-in-java

Comment: I think you should have a class for that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split a string in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java)

Comment: Might want to add the `regex` tag

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
String[] splits = contact.split(" ");
String name = splits[1];
```

Comment: will fail if name contains spaces

Comment: That is a usecase :p . Should do that logically

Comment: Thank you that was very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The answer of Viswanath shows how to retrieve the name from the string using string functions.

As an alternative you could consider to create a Contact class which holds the information:

```
 public class Contact {
     public String id;
     public String name;
     public String tel;

     public String toString() { return id + " " + name + " " + telNum; }
 }
```

and then pass a Contact object around instead of the string which represents the contact .

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. It is not possible for me to create another class due to restrictions. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

If your ID has only numbers and telephone number is starting with `+` or any digit then you can easily get name out of it.

Answer (score 0):

```
String name = contact.substring(contact.indexOf(" ", 0)+1, contact.indexOf(" ", contact.indexOf(" ", 0)+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

If id and telNum are two integer/long values you can do something like

```
int startIndex = contact.indexOf(" ");
int endIndex = contact.lastIndexOf(" ");
String name = contact.substring(startIndex, endIndex).trim();
```

It should be easier if your string has separators, like comma.

```
Ex.:  String contact = id + ", " + name + ", " + telNum;
```

In this case you could do the same of above but searching the index of "," or of ", ".