# Java: How to parse string?

Tags: java, parsing

Just started a programming class a few months ago, and I'm going over some review questions for a test. I'm not sure how to tackle this one. We have to format a few lines of text.

So something that looks like this: 2002/Bourne Identity/Action/1:58

Will have to look like this: 2002 - Bourne Identity Action 118 minutes

There are a few of these, and then we have to add up the total running time for each genre. Would I be right in using the split function here?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/950409/how-to-parse-this-string-in-java

Comment: Split the string on `/` and use the new String array to do the conversion accordingly

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that the input data are 4 variables. For example

```
public String parse(Integer year, String title, String genere, Date duration)
```

So you just have to operate the values. For example

```
return year + " - " + title + " " + genere + " " + toMinutes(duration) + " minutes"
```

where `toMinutes(duration)` is a function which parse a date to minutes.